# Angular prevent URL navigation but keep button navigation

Tags: angular, routes

I'm currently trying to prevent the user from navigate through the url itself. The user should only be able to navigate with buttons.

Basically my routing looks like this :

```
    const routes: Routes = [
  { path: 'form', component: FormComponent},
  { path: '', redirectTo: '/form', pathMatch: 'full' },
  { path: 'attachment', component: AttachmentComponent },
  { path: 'inbox', component: InboxComponent},
  { path: 'summary', component: SummaryComponent },
  { path: 'answer/:id', component: SummaryComponent}
];
```

So basically the user should be able to navigate to "/form" and "answer/:id" with the url itself but all the other routes like attachment/inbox/summary should be accessable by buttons only (e.g user goes on /form and theres a button which directs to attachment and summary or the user goes on "/answer:id" with a button with directs to inbox).

First thing I tried was setting the following parameter in my routing module(without setting a guard) :

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes, { initialNavigation: false })],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
```

Navigate through the url was not possible(which is good) and navigate with buttons worked but sadly I was not able to open my "form" or "answer" route which is necessary.
I tried setting up a guard :

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: 'form', component: FormComponent},
  { path: '', redirectTo: '/form', pathMatch: 'full' },
  { path: 'attachment', component: AttachmentComponent , canActivate:[DirectAccessGuard]},
  { path: 'inbox', component: InboxComponent, canActivate: [DirectAccessGuard]},
  { path: 'summary', component: SummaryComponent, canActivate: [DirectAccessGuard]},
  { path: 'answer/:id', component: SummaryComponent}
];
```

Guard :

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { CanActivate, ActivatedRouteSnapshot, RouterStateSnapshot, UrlTree, Router} from '@angular/router';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class DirectAccessGuard implements CanActivate {
  constructor(private router: Router) { }
  canActivate(
    next: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
    state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<boolean> | Promise<boolean> | boolean {
    // If the previous URL was blank, then the user is directly accessing this page
    return false;
  }
}
```

Opening "form" and "answer" with the url is possible but redirect to another component with a buttons doesn't work. Makes senses because I'm always returning false.
So my question is : Is it possible to get the target url in my guard?
If im on /form and I want to redirect to /attachment I know I can get "/form" with `this.router.url` but I want the target url ("/attachment" in this case). 
Or is there any other method to solve my problem?

Comment: Maybe this post can help you? [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36277506/prevent-routing-in-angular-when-user-manually-changes-url-in-browser-tab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36277506/prevent-routing-in-angular-when-user-manually-changes-url-in-browser-tab)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, It is possible to get the target url in guard from **ActivatedRouteSnapshot**.
The routeConfig property in ActivatedRouteSnapshot has a path property which gives target url.

I had tested as per the above mentioned scenarios,
Now the routes look like below,

```
const routes: Routes = [
    { path: 'form', component: FormComponent },
    { path: '', redirectTo: '/form', pathMatch: 'full' },
    { path: 'attachment', component: AttachmentComponent, canActivate: [DirectAccessGaurd] },
    { path: 'inbox', component: InboxComponent, canActivate: [DirectAccessGaurd] },
    { path: 'summary', component: SummaryComponent, canActivate: [DirectAccessGaurd] },
    { path: 'answer/:id', component: SummaryComponent, canActivate: [DirectAccessGaurd] },
    { path: '**', component: NotfoundComponent }
]
```

So, the actual logic goes in Gaurd,

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { CanActivate, RouterStateSnapshot, ActivatedRouteSnapshot, Router } from '@angular/router';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root'
})
export class DirectAccessGaurd implements CanActivate {

    constructor(private router: Router) { }
    canActivate(next: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<boolean> | Promise<boolean> | boolean {

        if(this.router.url === '/form') {
            if(next.routeConfig.path === 'attachment' || next.routeConfig.path === 'inbox') {
                return true;
            }
        }
        if(next.routeConfig.path === 'answer/:id') {
            return true; // To allow answer/:id route through url
        }
        if(this.router.url.startsWith('/answer/')) {
            if(next.routeConfig.path === 'summary') {
                return true;
            }
        }

        this.router.navigate(['/notfound'])
        return false;
    }
}
```

The logic is simple,
First I am checking for current url to be '/form', and then checking if target url is attachment or inbox, Then I am redirecting to those respectively.