# How can I stop a user to enter url with parameter? (If a user enters url with parameters manually, I want to make it redirect to home)

Tags: angular

My router is like this.

```
@NgModule({
imports: [
    RouterModule.forChild([
        {
            path: '',
            component: AppComponent,
            children: [
                {path: '', redirectTo: '/home', pathMatch: 'full'},
                { path: 'home', component: HomeComponent,  canActivate: [AppRouteGuard] },
                { path: 'books', component: BooksComponent, data: { permission: 'Pages.Books' }, canActivate: [AppRouteGuard] }, 
                { path: 'books/detail/:id', component: BooksComponent, data: { permission: 'Pages.Books' }, canActivate: [AppRouteGuard]},                   
                { path: '**', redirectTo: '/app/home'}                   
            ]
        }
    ])
],
exports: [RouterModule]
```

})

So when a user select a book from book page send book id to get details and url will be like

```
http://localhost:4200/app/prospects/detail/2045
```

But I don't want a user to type this url manually to get the details.
Is there any way to redirect to home if a user types url manually?

Comment: No you can't prevent user to enter the url and load specific component defined in router for that url

Comment: True, its impossible. But what do you want to avoid with this? Failure in detail page? If you have a detail call in the page and that call to the serverfails, with not found. You could navigate automatically to another page by writing the navigate in the error callback. But I don't think its a good idea. Its better to show the user that the detail could not be loaded

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Prevent routing in Angular when user manually changes url in browser tab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36277506/prevent-routing-in-angular-when-user-manually-changes-url-in-browser-tab)

Comment: That's not true, it's totally possible to prevent that. Do not listen to them.

Comment: But why would you do something like that ? What's your use-case ?

Comment: @leopal while it's indeed a duplicate, I'm not sure the other question has an answer. It's just a documentation explanation, but it doesn't really give the answer to the issue ...