# Angular Route url update

Tags: angular, angular-router-guards

I am working on a enhancement in my project.

Requirement : If user manually update the url, it should set back to present url.
for example:

**Intial URL:**
https://localhost:44319/client-acceptance/existing-client/0001100004/**3409**/client-extension-checklist

**Changed URL:**
https://localhost:44319/client-acceptance/existing-client/0001100004/**3410**/client-extension-checklist

**Expected URL:**
https://localhost:44319/client-acceptance/existing-client/0001100004/**3409**/client-extension-checklist

Here even though its changed to 3410, still it should change back to 3409, could you please help me with this issue.

Comment: Did you try to set a default route?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36277506/prevent-routing-in-angular-when-user-manually-changes-url-in-browser-tab)